# How to obtain EXIF info from picture in an excel worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How do I obtain the EXIF info like Latitude, Longitude, etc... from a shape picture in an excel worksheet using VBA?  And can it be obtained without extracting or copying the picture out of the worksheet or out of the zipped Excel workbook?

I am able to iterate through the zipped folder contents with the following code.

```
Public Sub ReadZip()
    Dim vZipFileName As Variant
    vZipFileName = "C:\Users\erogrou\Desktop\Test.zip"

    Dim objShell, objFolder
    Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(vZipFileName)

    Dim vFilename As Variant

    If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
        Debug.Print objFolder.self.Path

        For Each vFilename In objFolder.items
            Debug.Print vFilename
        Next

    End If

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately for you there is a beautiful piece [of coding](http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Extracting-GPS-data-from-JPEG-files) by Andrew Phillips from Australia's North Central Catchment Management Authority that does exactly this.

It is provided as a class module so I haven't looked to re-list this here

The current code can be imported from Access to Excel, in my case I needed to change the functions from 32 to 64 bit as so:

> Private Declare Function VirtualAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Address As Long, ByVal Size As Long, ByVal AllocationType As Long, ByVal Protect As Long) As Long

to this using `PntSafe`

> Private Declare PtrSafe Function VirtualAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Address As Long, ByVal Size As Long, ByVal AllocationType As Long, ByVal Protect As Long) As Long

Comment: Thanks for this referral and your insight into the 64 bit Excel implementation.  The exif info is a big part of the solution and I will definitely be pursuing this.  As for the other part of my question.  Can the contents of a zipped file be read or edited or saved to without first exporting the file to a temporary working location?  I am presuming this is not possible because the file is compressed and it appears it can't even be worked on like that in Windows.  Even a simple text file is opened in a temp location and you can't save it directly back to the zipped location you opened it from.

Comment: Hi, does this approach still work? My Access / Excel (Version 1811 - Office 365) crashes when using the fixed code.

Answer (score 3):

The rendered pictures in Excel are typically embedded inside an enhanced metafile (EMF). You'd need to copy the metafile to the clipboard as an EMF, then enumerate the records of the EMF and extract the JPG, then parse the EXIF data from the JPG information.

Alternatively, if the Excel file is saved and is in XLSX/XLSM format, you can extract the JPG from the compressed XLSX/XLSM container and then parse that image for the EXIF data.

Neither approach is trivial to implement, and in both cases, it would be easier with .NET.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I am committed to using Excel VBA on this one because it supplements a lot of existing VBA code.  So, if I was to only deal with Excel xlsx/m workbooks where they are stored in the OpenXML format, would I be able to read directly the EXIF info from the files stored within, provided of course they are JPEGs with EXIF?  I think to begin I need to be able to read the contents of a file in the xlsm workbook and I have found a few examples of this but these examples all export the files first but I want to read them directly.  Is it possible to read a file directly?

Comment: Looks like @brettdj's answer will extract the EXIF data, but you still need to extract the files and read the XML to find the images. .NET makes unzipping relatively easy, but for a pure VBA solution, you'd need to extract the files to a temporary location using code similar to Ron de Bruin's [example](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm). Even with the files extracted, you need to be able to interpret the *multiple* xml files that describe the relationships, layout and content of the file, in order to identify which image is which.

Comment: You should perhaps try changing the `xlsx` file extension to `zip`, and exploring the contents of the file, to confirm that the images actually have the EXIF data that you need, *before* you spend too much time pursuing this.

Comment: Changing the extension to zip and reading the zipped files contents is particularly where I was going with the second part of my question.  I am currently doing exactly that and am able to iterate through the zipped files names but I don't know how or if the zipped files contents can be read directly from the zipped folder.  An example how to do that would be great because every example I have found extracts/copies the files to a temporary folder to read and as you indicated is very inefficient.

Comment: @RRR How are you currently reading the file names from within the zip?