# When I try to run Excel VBA code, gives me error message: Runtime error '-2145320854 (8021006a)?

Tags: excel, vba, file, properties, geolocation

I've been trying to create this code using VBA to extract the GPS data from a set of image files in a folder and paste the data into a collection of rows in an excel table. I have no previous experience with VBA and am still a relative novice when it comes to the coding world in general so I have no clue what I'm doing but I made this code that I thought would work using random posts of similar things I found online. Now the issue I'm facing is the error code that is shown in the title of the post. I tried googling the issue but to no avail as the one link with a similar situation was never resolved. This project has taken up quite a bit of time and my boss, who I am terrified of, is starting to passive aggressively breath down my neck for it. I am asking for your assistance sharks, with an investment of giving me the solution, in exchange for 15% of my company, Save-Me-From-My-Scary-Boss Inc.

Here's the code I used:

```
Sub ExtractPhotoData()

'Declare variables
Dim FSO As Object
Dim SourceFolder As Object
Dim FileItem As Object
Dim Image As Object
Dim RowCounter As Integer

RowCounter = 1

'Set up the file system object and source folder
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 9).Value)

'Loop through each file in the source folder
For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files


    'Load the image
    Set Image = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    Image.LoadFile FileItem.Path
        
    'Extract the longitude, latitude, and altitude data
    Dim Longitude As Long
    Dim Latitude As Long
    Dim Altitude As Long
    Longitude = Image.Properties("GPS Longitude").Value
    Latitude = Image.Properties("GPS Latitude").Value
    Altitude = Image.Properties("GPS Altitude").Value
        
    'Paste the data into the worksheet
    RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
    Cells(RowCounter, 1).Value = FileItem.Name
    Cells(RowCounter, 2).Value = Longitude
    Cells(RowCounter, 3).Value = Latitude
    Cells(RowCounter, 4).Value = Altitude

Next FileItem

End Sub
```

Comment: I would start commenting out your code line by line .. Starting with the worksheet, then declaring the Long Lat, etc etc .. Find the line(s) that are causing the issue that way.  Then ask the question **"Why does this line (these lines) break my code?"** ...  Since the problem cannot be duplicated, narrowing it down for the community will be helpful in your quest for a solution.

Comment: Whoops. I forgot to mention this. I tried debugging it, and I found the code was crashing at the part where the properties values are assigned to the variables, so at Longitude = Image.Properties("GPS Longitude").Value. I think it might have something to do with the use of WIA and Image.Properties but I'm not certain

Comment: I do not think there is a space between gps and the other words.  See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416646/excel-vba-open-folder-and-get-gps-info-exif-of-each-files-in-it-2

Comment: Also note that they return arrays and not a single value, so you will need to deal with the array as a single cell will not hold an array.

Answer (score 2):

The error you get is "Name not found". You get it when you try to access a property that doesn't exist. Not all images have GPS information stored, so you should be prepared.

Also, as far as I know, the GPS-property names doesn't contain a space, and you need to be careful with the upper- vs lowercases. It should be `Image.Properties("GpsLongitude")` ([see here](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/GPS.html))

You can get a list of all properties of an image with

```
Dim p
For Each p In Image.Properties
    Debug.Print FileItem.Name, p.Name
Next
```

Next issue is that the properties for longitude and latitude doesn't return simple values. I checked with an image file and got and object of type `IVector` for the values, containing 3 single values that define degree, minute and second, and you need additionally the property "GpsLongitudeRef" to get N/S resp E/W.

For the altitude, you can read the value as `Long`, however there is more: the property contains for example also the unit ("m") and the "GpsAltitudeRef" defines the reference ("Sea level").

I ended up with some example code

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim longitude As String
longitude = getLongLat(Image.Properties("GpsLongitude").Value, Image.Properties("GpsLongitudeRef").Value)
Dim latitude As String
latitude = getLongLat(Image.Properties("GpsLatitude").Value, Image.Properties("GpsLatitudeRef").Value)

Dim altitude As Long
altitude = Image.Properties("GpsAltitude").Value
On Error Resume Next

Debug.Print FileItem.Name, longitude, latitude, altitude
```

and the helper function

```
Function getLongLat(vector As Object, ref As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    getLongLat = vector(1) & ":" & vector(2) & ":" & vector(3) & " " & ref
End Function
```

Of course it's up to you to convert longitude and latitude into numbers.